# Where can i find Enterprise Architect MDG Object Tag Guid?

Tags: enterprise-architect

In Enterprise Architect,
While i have creating MDG technology objects into Enterprise Architect,the object based on Tag,the tag guid contains first 16 characters are static(below i just highlighted static characters) and other 16 characters are changed dynamically.
Where can i get this static characters?

{**CB2DC399-2D11-202d**-8ADB-00882A2C86B7}

{**CB2DC399-2D11-202d**-A3FC-97A8949AF987}

Example:
i was created a BPMN2.0::Activity in Enterprise Architect,It created along with some predefined Tags.

[image]

and the tag Guids are 
[image]

While i have trying to change(Update) this static characters in guid,tag was moved under User defined group.

if we give guid like first 16 characters static and dynamic(changed) in other 16 characters,then the tag would be created under "BPMN2.0::Activity" Group.

So where the static characters in guid is coming from?

Thanks

Comment: How, what, why? AFAIK GUID's in EA are just random GUID's. Can you explain a bit more about the problem you are having, and how you discovered this.

Comment: I just trying to create MDG object directly in Database.
For example,lets take **BPMN2.0::Activity** or any MDG Object along with tagged values.
In Enterprise Architect,the object created along with predefined Tags.
similarly,i have tired to create tag for "BPMN2.0::Activity"with randam guids in Database.it added under User defined group.then i fouund like the guid first 16 characters are static.So i tried by kept first 16 character and remaining appended with dynamic characters,then it will added under respective MDG Tag group.would you able to get my point?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are inserting in the database directly? It is much easier to use the API and let EA create all the necessary records.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this GUID is created from an internal value EA creates from the loaded MDG value. Any MDG related data are held in EA's internal memory and there is neither an API nor any database table you can access. If you really want to add tagged values directly you need to retrieve an existing one and extract the prefix. However, as Geert points out, you should just create TVs of an MDG via the API by specifying the FQN.